# How to run models with string and numbers

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a data set that is dealing with flight data. i am trying to predict wether a flight will be delayed or not. However, i am getting stuck because I have two non numeric columns. One is the Destination column which is a city code and the other is the airline code.

There is 155 different destinations, and i don't want to add 154 columns to make it binary.

Is it possible to have the models ignore the columns without deleting them?

Comment: you can use scikitlearn oneHotEncoder to encode your categorical data  https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html  Yes, it will create 155 columns, but what's the problem? You cannot treat this data as numerical in 
a single columns because then category 1 will be closer to category 2 than to category 3, which doesn't make sense with categorical data. So use the OneHotEncoder and create the 155 columns

Comment: I'm trying not to add all the columns that oneHotEncoder creates.

Comment: you mean you want your model to only classify let's say 50 of your 155 different destinations?

Comment: No, the y is wether the flight left on time or not. the destination and airline code are part of the X.

Comment: Do the models manipulate the data? What i am asking is can I simply remove these two columns, split the data. Have the models do their thing and then add them back?

Comment: I'd suggest you take a look at how categorical data classifiers work. Your data needs to be a vector, where each dimension is a feature. When you have categorical data, you cannot encode different categories into a single dimension, because then there will be a concept of distance between categories, which you don't want. So what you do is make each category in a separate dimension. You will have then 155 dimensions (which is perfectly fine) You can apply dimensionality reduction methods like PCA if you want to have less dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [pipeline](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) that will drop certain columns you do not want to use before feeding the data in the model:

```py
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline

# Specify which columns you want the model to ignore
cols_drop = ['Destination', 'column_2']

# Create the preprocessor that will ignore the columns
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('Drop features', 'drop', cols_drop)
        ])

# Grouping your model and the preprocessor in a pipeline
model_pipe = Pipeline([
    ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
    ('model', model),
])
```

Here 'model' is your sklearn estimator (e.g. LogisticRegression() or DecisionTreeClassifier(), etc).

You can fit or predict with the model_pipe like you would with another estimator.